# Why cookie is sent in HTTP post when xhr.withCredentials = true;

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cors

If you run below JS code, it will make HTTP POST request to server with cookies, but POST response is blocked by browser because `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` header wasn't present in response from yahoo.com.

My question is, why browser allow POST request with cookie and doesn't do a preflight, as xhr.withCredentials=true, sends the cookie?

Damage to server is already done, even if browser doesn't allow JS to access the POST request's response?

This looks like CSRF vulnerability.

Am I missing anything here?

Update: Is this the case where CSRF token is required?

```js
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if ((xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) || xhr.status == 304) { 
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
            } else {
                console.log("Request was unsuccessful: " + xhr.status);
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    xhr.open("post", "https://yahoo.com/example", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    xhr.send("a=5");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>


<p>Hello</p>




</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's always been possible to make a POST request with application/x-www-form-urlencoded data to any URL by simply submitting a form.

XHR and co don't change that.

There's no point in adding extra security there because that horse has already bolted.

So, yes, there is a risk of CSRF, but not a *new* risk. Sites need to take [the usual defenses against CSRF](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html).